# Is Standard American Accent an old British Accent before 17th century?

Tags: pronunciation

I heard that American accent is like British accent before 17th Century.

About 17th century, in Britain, there was a movement of changing the accent, which creates a new Standard British accent (like the one you hear in BBC news). Meanwhile, the American still uses the old English accent from old British accent (the British one before 17th Century).

For example, see the Sound "R" like in "Far". The American curls the tongue, while the British does not. Before 17th century, the American & British have the same or similar accent. It's only different after the movement of changing in Britain in 17th century.

Is that true?

I personally feel that the American accent is more natural.

Comment: All native accents are natural. We can't say CanE sounds more natural than AusE.

Comment: No, it's not. The Standard American accent has kept some features of 17th century British (we pronounce all the 'r's), but has lost many other features (we rhyme *father* and *bother*). Both American and British English have changed radically since the 17th century, and they may be more similar to each other than to 17th century British English (Shakespeare rhymed *wind* with *find*; and *memory* with *never die*).

Comment: Why would you think changes in a dialect constitute a ‘movement’, like it’s a political thing you have to go and vote on? Or indeed that an accent can just remain the same for 300 years? _Every_ dialect of _every_ language in the world is in constant change all the time. Both British and American dialects have changed drastically since the 17th century, but in different ways. This is natural—it’s how new languages appear.

Comment: @PeterShor You people still talk about a *British accent* as though it is, or was, a single entity. There has never been anything that one would describe as a *British accent*. There are a collective of regional accents and there is something called RP which is spoken by about 3% of the UK population, which evolved in the modern period. 'American English' which is far more widespread than RP, bears similarities to a number of UK accents, most notably the South West, with its rolling rhotic 'r' sound. But I would suggest there was also a large component of Irish  in 'American'.

Comment: All accents, dialects, and languages change, constantly. Therefore the question makes false presuppositions and can't have an answer.

Comment: @PeterShor, Shakespeare was a brummie, and brummies still rhyme  memory with never die!

Comment: I heard that the American accent is more like the original British too but...really? We used to sound like that? Oh God...

Comment: JohnLawler Isn't the answer just *No* - for the reasons that you and @Janus have given? They'd make good answers, imo. It the kind of thing I hear a lot of - so would be useful for readers!

Comment: I don't believe in this "standard American accent". There is no such thing, just a lot of regional variations, some major and some minor.

Comment: @NadjaCS You are correct:  [“General American doesn’t exist. He was demoted to private or sergeant a long, long time ago.”](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/is-there-a-place-in-america-where-people-speak-without-accents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really, no.

All English spoken today has changed somewhat since the 17th Century, and for as long as we know there have always been many different English accents.

In some ways American English accents are more conservative than many UK accents. The most distinctive one is the retention of the `/r/` sound at the end of words. This is a feature shared with some UK accents, e.g. in the West Country (except before vowels when it is still pronounced in most UK dialects).

In other ways, American English accents have innovated: for instance, vowel sounds have changed considerably in virtually all varieties of American English in a way which makes them markedly different from any dialect found in the UK.

Some changes took place both sides of the Atlantic: the `/j/` sound after the `/n/` in *new* (and after other certain other consonants) is no longer pronounced by many speakers of American English and it is also absent in speakers from parts of the East of England and the Midlands.

And of course, contact was not completely severed: Americanisms have crept into UK dialects and Britishishms have made their way westwards too.

Comment: There are still lots of Americans who pronounce the /j/ after /n/ in *new* and related words (although this pronunciation appears to be slowly dying out in AmE).

Answer (score 0):

I have never met any American to speak like that. British people do, though.
Where do these Americans live? I am from New York state.